# Animate in sync the blinking animation of multiple buttons using Storyboard in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Notice that I am using UWP.
Okay, so I have a custom button that starts blinking when it is toggled on, and then stops blinking when toggled off. Now say that I have another instance of that blinking button type. If the first button is already toggled on and blinking, and then I toggle the second button on to begin blinking, I want the second button to blink in sync with the first button. So when the first button blinks on or off, I want the second button to be doing the exact same thing in sync. Is there ANY explanation for achieving this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, so I use a Storyboard and a ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames element. The animation is triggered when the button is checked on via a tapped event, and then stops when tapped again. The animation's RepeatBehavior is set to forever. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest solution is to rewind the storyboard of all custom buttons to zero when a (new) blinking button is activated. Rewind them using [Storyboard.Seek()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.seek(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
myStoryboard.Seek(myCustomButton, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
```

Further reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-seek-a-storyboard

Comment: Thanks for the reply and great idea. Will def see if it works in my code.